# np.argsort(np.zeros(17)) gives strange order

Tags: python, numpy, np.argsort

As the title suggests, the `np.argsort(np.zeros(n))` can gives right result if `n<=16`, otherwise, it will give a strange result, e.g.,

```py
np.argsort(np.zeros(17))
# array([ 0, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9, 15,  8,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  7, 16], dtype=int64)

np.argsort(np.zeros(18))
# array([ 0, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1, 16, 17], dtype=int64)
```

Can anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: `argsort` is not stable by default.

Comment: Ah, thanks @QuangHoang, it explains everything! Would you know any equivalent functions but stable? Thanks!

Comment: There is a `kind='mergesort'` option for [`argsort/sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

Comment: Thanks so much, @QuangHoang! You saved my night!

Comment: Here's a link for anyone who doesn't automatically know what "stable" means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39447202/6030926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try **‘stable’** mode will work.

```py
np.argsort(np.zeros(17), kind='stable')
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
      dtype=int64)
```